# Apache redirect to language specific domain

Tags: apache

I'm looking for a solution to redirect to two different domains according to the language set in the browser.

People will access **maindomain.com/path** and should be redirected to **english.com/path** as default and to **french.com/path** if the browser language is set to french.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @swmcdonnell I managed to get this to work. This is what I came up with, it may be possible to simplify, but this works for me :

```
RewriteEngine On

#if browser is set to a german type language and on maindomain.com (de, de-ch, ...)
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^de.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^maindomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.maindomain.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$  https://www.german.com$1 [L,R=301]

#default to french.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^maindomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.maindomain.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.french.com$1 [L,R=301]
```

(the languages are what I actually use)

Answer (score 0):

In Apache, you can use the mod_rewrite to redirect based on language. For example, in your Virtual Hosts file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^maindomain.com/(.*) https://english.com/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^fr [NC]
RewriteRule ^maindomin.com/(.*) https://french.com/$1 [L]
```

Make sure you enable the mod_rewrite module with: **a2enmod rewrite**